# Colorblind and colors. Which elements of the VS2019 text editor relate to the C # language?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, colors, text-editor, color-blindness

I am color-blind. I'm trying to change the colors of the Visual Studio community text editor by changing the options.

Could you tell me what are the items I can change in the (very long) list?

Please, only those that are taken into account when I code in C#.

[image: Daltonic color sheme]

Comment: Can you take a screenshot and point to the colors you mean?

Comment: Thank you @abdusco for your interest in my problem.
I posted an image while editing my question.
I don't know if this is the right way to go.

Comment: Does this help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-change-fonts-and-colors-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019#use-visual-studio-extra-contrast

Comment: I searched all over the internet for a list of C # target items, like "numbers" "User Types - Classes" ... But I couldn't find anything ... Has anyone done this search yet?

Comment: Thank you for this link but of course I have this page and others in my favorites. But I don't know what impacts C #. So I change a color, I apply and I check. If nothing changes I go back to put the color and I test the next one ... You see the §è'u§è'§ ;-)

Answer (score 4):

**Solution 1:**

If you're on Windows 10, leverage [the color filters in the operating system](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/use-color-filters-in-windows-10-43893e44-b8b3-2e27-1a29-b0c15ef0e5ce):

[image]

**Solution 2:**

Check https://github.com/Microsoft/VS-ColorThemes for well done themes.

However, as you'll notice, those files are ~8000 LOC each, not easy to find your way out in them.

But maybe you'll find a theme that may be a good fit for you without any edit, so try them first.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the preview in the settings window isn't much of a help. So you have to know what you're looking for.

[image: preview]

These should get you started to change the things you marked:

| Item | Setting name |
| --- | --- |
| `static`, `class`, `string`, `return` etc. | Keyword |
| variable names (`x` in `var x = ...`) | Identifier |
| type names (`Console`) | Type, Navigable Symbol, Symbol definition, Symbol reference |